# Ruby on Rails 4: How to authenticate to Azure AD from Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am developing a Rails 4 web application and i am planning to authenticate a user from my Windows Azure AD.

For that i have subscribed to Windows Azure and created Active Directory. I then created an application inside AD to get Client and Secret ID to access API exposed by windows Azure from my Rails web application.

For this i am planning to use Devise gem . Is this the right solution or is there any other libraries available to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've no experience of working on Azure with Ruby, but the "Windows Azure SDK for Ruby" ([Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby), [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/azure/frames)) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking for anything, but [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/omercs/9918845) has the requisite request code using the [OAuth2 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth2). If you were ultimately able to get things working with another means (Devise, etc.), I'd also be interested to know what you did.

Here's the code from the Gist as packaged into a controller by [omercs](https://github.com/omercs):

```
require 'oauth2'

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  # You need to configure a tenant at Azure Active Directory(AAD) to register web app and web service app
  # You will need two entries for these app at the AAD portal
  # You will put clientid and clientsecret for your web app here
  # ResourceId is the webservice that you registered
  # RedirectUri is registered for your web app
  CLIENT_ID = 'b6a42...'
  CLIENT_SECRET = 'TSbx..'
  AUTHORITY = 'https://login.windows.net/'
  AUTHORIZE_URL = "/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize"
  TOKEN_URL = "/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token"
  RESOURCE_ID = 'https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/AllHandsTry' #ResourceId or ResourceURI that you registered at Azure Active Directory
  REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/welcome/callback'

  def index
    update_token
    if session['access_token']
      # show main page and use token
      redirect_to welcome_use_token_path  
    else
      # start authorization
      client = get_client
      a = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:client_id => CLIENT_ID, :resource => RESOURCE_ID, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
      redirect_to(a)  
    end
  end

  def callback
    begin
      @code = params[:code]
      client = get_client
      # post token to mobile service api
      #token = client.auth_code.get_token(CGI.escape(@code), :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
      # id_token token.params["id_token"]
      #multi resource token token.params["resource"]
      token = client.auth_code.get_token(@code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI, )
      session['access_token'] = token.token
      session['refresh_token'] = token.refresh_token
      session['expire_at'] = token.expire_at  
      session['instance_url']  = token.params['instance_url']
      redirect '/'
    rescue => exception
       output = '<html><body><p>'
       output += "Exception: #{exception.message}<br/>"+exception.backtrace.join('<br/>')
       output += '</p></body></html>'
    end
  end

  def update_token
    puts "update token inside"
    token = session['access_token']
    refresh_token = session['refresh_token']  
    expire_at = session['expire_at']
    @access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(get_client, { :access_token => token, :refresh_token =>  refresh_token, :expire_at => expire_at, :header_format => 'Bearer %s' } )
    if @access_token.expired?
       puts "refresh token"
       @access_token = @access_token.refresh!;
       session['access_token'] = @access_token.token
       session['refresh_token'] = @access_token.refresh_token
       session['expire_at'] = @access_token.expire_at  
       session['instance_url']  = @access_token.params['instance_url']
    end
  end

  # send post request to webservice to send token and create a post request
  def use_token
    # we got the token and now it will posted to the web service in the header
    # you can specify additional headers as well
    # token is included by default
    update_token
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/') do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
      faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
    end
    response = conn.get do |req|                          
      req.url '/api/WorkItem' 
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+@access_token.token
    end
    @out = response.body
  end

  def get_client
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, :site => AUTHORITY, :authorize_url =>  AUTHORIZE_URL, :token_url => TOKEN_URL )
    client
  end
end
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is true. I'll revise the answer.